# Why does my YouTube video show more visits when I check it anonymously?

Tags: youtube, account-management, statistics

I have a video on YouTube (a cinema tutorial), but when I visit the site anonymously it says that I have 188 views.

When I log in with my account that I used to upload the video it says it was viewed only 31 times.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

As a logged in user you will get unique visits and as an anonymous user you will get total views (including unique+return visits).